# Ext4 file system format drive does not show in Windows 8

Tags: 13.04, windows-8, ext4, file-format

To install Ubuntu 13.04 I formatted a drive with Ext4 file system format. After format I can't open the drive from windows 8 Explorer. Whenever I try to open the drive following error shows :[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is more of a Windows question in my opinion, or at least a significant part. Consider asking such questions on [Superuser.com](http://superuser.com) instead, next time.

Answer (score 5):

You can install a Windows filesystem driver to read Ext2/3/4 filesystems: [Ext2Fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/). This message you're seeing is because Windows does not recognize these filesystems and offers you to reformat it using a Windows-native filesystem (NTFS/FAT32).

See [Ext2 File System Driver for Windows (sourceforge.net)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/) and [Ext2Fsd Project](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) for more information on how to install it. While the name suggests it's for Ext2 only, it works for 3 and 4 as well.

However, for sharing files between the two operating systems in a dual boot configuration, I would prefer to use either NTFS or FAT32 on that partition. But then it won't be possible to use this partition for Ubuntu system file (boot drive) or home directory, because of permission features it is lacking.

Answer (score 1):

**Windows cannot open Ext- filesystems** by default.
There is a programm for Windows to open Ext-filesystems, but i don't know the name or how good it is.

Answer (score 1):

Widows doesn't read Ext4 by default.

Try Ext2Read.  Ext2Read is an explorer like utility to explore ext2/ext3/ext4 files. It now supports LVM2 and EXT4 extents. It can be used to view and copy files and folders. It can recursively copy entire folders. It can also be used to view and copy disk and file.

To download click [Ext2Read](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/files/latest/download)

<sup>Source:Sourceforge</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled on this topic and i found that i could read ext4 from windows 8.1 using total commander with an ext4-plugin. http://www.ghisler.com/ and http://www.ghisler.com/plugins.htm#filesys choose ext4 from file system extensions. Dont forget to always start total cmd as admin when you are using it to read ext filesystems.
Then after download mark the plugin in total cmd and press enter and follow instructions.

Hope it helps.

Jimboo.